# select date between query mssql

Tags: sql-server

I have query:

```
SELECT  Firma, Czas, Dzien, Opis, Kto, ID
FROM    Rok2016
WHERE   (Dzien BETWEEN @z1 AND @z2) 
AND ((@x='*' AND Firma!='')OR(@x!='*' AND Firma=@x))
AND ((@y='*' AND Kto!='')OR(@y!='*' AND Kto=@y))
```

z1 and z2 are format date like DD/MM/YYYY.

This displays all records between days and doesnt consider month at all. Please help

Comment: What is your question, here?

Comment: Probably because your datatype is character data instead of datetime. It would help if you tagged only the DBMS you are actually working with. mysql <> sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL server:

If you want to compare dates, you should be using a date (or datetime/2) data types.

Using [**`set dateformat dmy;`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) to avoid format conflicts in the `convert()`:

```
set dateformat dmy;

SELECT  Firma, Czas, Dzien, Opis, Kto, ID
FROM    Rok2016
WHERE   (convert(date,Dzien) BETWEEN convert(date,@z1) AND convert(date,@z2)) 
  AND ((@x='*' AND Firma!='')OR(@x!='*' AND Firma=@x))
  AND ((@y='*' AND Kto!='')OR(@y!='*' AND Kto=@y))
```

Comment: @JohnCappelletti http://rextester.com/EOY95237 `set dateformat dmy;` works as well.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti ^.^

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Using style `103` with `convert()` would be better if `Dzien` was stored as `mdy` and the parameters were `dmy` though.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your @z1 and @z2 into an actual date like so

```
Select convert(date,'15/06/2016',103)
```

Returns

```
2016-06-15
```

Or in your case

```
...
Dzien BETWEEN convert(date,@z1,103) AND convert(date,@z2,103)
...
```